# How can we split a string by sentence as a delimiter (two words with space between)?

Tags: java, string, split

I need to split a string using a substring(two words with space in between).

```
String str = hello hi how are you?
```

I tried:

```
String[] strs = str.split("hi how");
```

required output: ["hello", "are you?"]
what i get: ["hello hi how are you?]

Comment: that is not the result of that split.

Comment: [I can't reproduce your observations](https://rextester.com/AOR89281).

Comment: Your code is working fine.

Comment: working fine for me.

Comment: @AmitBera  i dont know why its not working for me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I saw your code but don't know why it's not working. Thanks anyway for trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with something like

```
str.split(Pattern.quote("hi how"));
```

Comment: @Stultuske indeed, I didn't even notice the quote was unecessary... :) A bit tired...

Comment: Pattern.quote works fine. I still don't why .split() simply didn't work. But thanks @spi for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use split function of String Class.
For example i want to split countries names by space

```
String countries = "USA UK UAE";
String[] countriesList = names.split(" ");

// Now Result can be taken from countriesList Array 

String usaString = countriesList [0]; // contains USA
```